# Setting up existing Cakephp 3 project to local XAMPP

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp, cakephp-3.0

So I'm setting up an existing Cakephp 3 project named CakeApp to my local XAMPP. I put the CakeApp folder inside `C:\\xampp\htdocs\` and I am able to access its main page in `http://localhost/CakeApp`. It automatically redirects me to `http://localhost/CakeApp/users/login` which is the supposed main page. I'm trying to access the Cakephp's main `src\Pages\home.ctp` though to check first if the project was successfully set up in my local XAMPP. So in `config\routes.php`, I changed:

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

$routes->connect('/',
        ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index']
    );

$routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');     });
```

to

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

$routes->connect('/',
        ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'home']
    );

$routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');    });
```

Now `http://localhost/CakeApp` is giving me an `Error: The requested address '/CakeApp/' was not found on this server.`

So in `src\Pages\home.ctp`, I commented out:

```
if (!Configure::read('debug')):
    throw new NotFoundException();
endif;
```

It is still giving me the same `Error: The requested address '/CakeApp/' was not found on this server.` though. So in `src\Controller\PagesController.php`, I found out that there was no action for `home`. So I created:

```
public function home() {
}
```

Now, going to `http://localhost/CakeApp` automatically redirects me again to `http://localhost/CakeApp/users/login`. I'm trying to access `home.ctp` which gives me information about the Cakephp project set up.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: why don't you use Server Shell? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/server-shell.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you comment all the codes in the routes.php  then replace to this code

```
<?php

use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::defaultRouteClass('Route');

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});

Router::extensions('json', 'xml');
/**
 * Load all plugin routes.  See the Plugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
Plugin::routes();
?>
```

Comment: by the way where did you get  this in routes.php                                
   $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');